# Conditional tag with DateInterval

Tags: php, dateinterval, conditionaltagsupport

how to use conditional tags using DateInterval with hour for scale in PHP

for example
i will add text "**active**" if at 21:00 until 23:00

```
<?php 
  $Hr = date('H:i'); 
  if($hr == 21:00 - 23:00) { 
    echo "active"; 
  }
  else { 
    echo "not active"; 
  }
```

Comment: explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have this code
<?php
 $Hr = date('H:i'); 
if($hr == 21:00 - 23:00){
 echo "active";
}else{
 echo "not active";
}

Comment: where is your code ?? Edit your question by adding your code also.

Comment: Sorry this my code

<?php $Hr = date('H:i'); if($hr == 21:00 - 23:00){ echo "active"; }else{ echo "not active"; }

Comment: Read this question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php

Comment: @awnew use strtotime(): function to compare the time in php

Comment: @pranavm.s : can you enhance my code,
help me please :)

Comment: @awnew please have a look at below i have posted the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, use DateTime to compare time.

```
$time1 = new DateTime('21:00');
$time2 = new DateTime('23:00');
$interval = $time1->diff($time2);
//echo $interval;
$diff =  $interval->format('%H').":".$interval->format('%I');
$Hr = date('H:i'); 
echo $diff." == ".$Hr."\n";

if($hr == $diff) { 
    echo "active"; 
}
else { 
   echo "not active"; 
}
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/675947)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$Hr = date('H:i'); 

  if(strtotime($hr)>strtotime(21:00) && strtotime($hr)<strtotime(23:00) ){
    echo "active";
  }else{
     echo "not active"; 
  }
```

Please try this this may work.

Comment: excelent...
bit mistake on my files and successful by adding 'in ('21: 00')

thanks